# Why doesn't `integer?` only succeed for things of type Integer?

Tags: typed-racket

It seems like `integer?` can succeed for ... non-integers? Why doesn't this code type-check?

```
#lang typed/racket

(define x : Real 134)

(define y : Integer (cond [(integer? x) x]
                          [else (error "not an integer")]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're absolutely right, the `integer?` predicate doesn't just succeed for things of type Integer, it also succeeds for inexact reals like `3.0`. You probably wanted to use the predicate `exact-integer?`, instead:

```
#lang typed/racket

(define x : Real 134)

(define y : Integer (cond [(exact-integer? x) x]
                          [else (error "not an integer")]))
```

This code type-checks and runs.

The same goes for `nonnegative-integer?`, use instead `exact-nonnegative-integer?`.